# Remove null params in HttpParams

Tags: angular, query-string, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, querystringparameter

I have a criteria object for which some attributes can be null, if I don't do anything the query string include those like `&p=undefined` which is not desirable since at the WebApi these come as`"null"` instead of `null` 
So given this in the Angular client

```
      return this._http
          .get<ExposureDifference[]>(AppSettings.ExposureRunDataQueryString, {params : <any>criteria, withCredentials: true}) 
          .catch<any, ExposureDifference[]>(this._trace.handleError("GET " + AppSettings.ExposureRunDataQueryString + criteria, []))
          .finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
```

I could get the query string as

```
http://localhost:63037/api/exposureRuns/data/?id=3&secsymb=undefined&fund=EL&esectype=SWAP_CDS
```

Is there a way to exclude the undefined parameters from the query string?

Comment: You may also want to keep an eye on this thread:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20564

Many users complained about this behavior of Angular2 given the fact that it didn't to behave like this (null/undefined values where being completely omitted from the query string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should filter them client side using JavaScript's [`delete` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) keyword if they have a value of `undefined` (which is different than the key not being in the object at all):

```
if (queryObject.secsymb === undefined) {
  delete queryObject.secsymb;
}
```

and then use a default method parameter in your controller method:

```
GetExposureRunsData(int id, string fund, SecType sectype, string secsymb = null)
```

If you ensure that the query string parameter is not included then your parameter will default to `null`

Comment: Hi @Alex M The undefined attribute was not deleted, typescript set it to null instead of undefined and the WebApi got it as "null" so the problem was not solved

Answer (score 3):

That's what I usually do. Works like a charm.

```js
    getDocumentsReport(filter: object) {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        Object.keys(filter).forEach(
            key => filter[key] && (params = params.append(key, filter[key]))
        );
    
        return this.http.get<object>(
            environment.apiServer + '/api/reports/documents',
            {
                params
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
removeNullValuesFromQueryParams(params: HttpParams) {
  const paramsKeysAux = params.keys();
  paramsKeysAux.forEach((key) => {
    const value = params.get(key);
    if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
      params['map'].delete(key);
    }
  });

  return params;
}
```

And in your Intercept Service, set the Params of Request equals the return of the **removeNullValuesFromQueryParams**(req.params), function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
this.httpClient.get('../api/path', { 
  params: Object.entries(queryParameterObject).reduce((queryParams, [key, value]) => queryParams.set(key, value), new HttpParams());
});
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I am  getting params as `"null"` with the above code - so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: It looks like you are converting your parameters into a string before calling this. If you need to convert them into string, you can do that in `queryParams.set(key, value)` instead and pass the correct value of the parameters as input.